# Placing PHP variable inside SQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to send city from a page to another and then show items from database where city is the mentioned city but this code does not return any results. Please guide. I am sure everything else is fine with the code.

```
$city = $_POST["city"];
$sql = "SELECT id,full_name, email, password,full_address,city,age,contact_number,gender,education FROM users WHERE city=$city";
```

Comment: It seems you sent the variable you need. Now you need to use mysqli or PDO to fetch data from database. You can read more at http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php or http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Comment: @timgavin This is a very bad idea and causes direct SQL injection possibilities...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you're not even executing the request on your mysql server, but if you are using PDO (what you SHOULD do), just do something like this:

```
<?php
$bdd = new PDO(etc);
$req = $bdd->prepare("SELECT id,full_name, email, password,full_address,city,age,contact_number,gender,education FROM users WHERE city=?");
$req->execute(array($_POST['city']));
print_r($req->fetchAll());
?>
```

And here you go, $req->fetchAll() will return you an array with each element returned by your request, and the best part is that prepare will prevent you from every SQLi

Edit: You can use short syntax for array [$_POST['city']] or old and complete syntax: array($_POST['city'])

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you `$bdd` for your database connection variable? I'm clearly missing something, so I am now curious, as stated.

Comment: $bdd mean "base de données", french word of database. Since I'm French and always used this, I instinctively put it everywhere. But yeah, in an English board it could sound strange for readers.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. I never considered it being language thing, so appreciate the knowledge. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

```
// strip tags from the input
$city = strip_tags($_POST["city"]);

// escape the input to prevent sql injection (assuming you are using mysqli() as your connection method...)
$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($city);

// your query does not work because you need to put strings inside single quotes
$sql = "SELECT id,full_name, email, password,full_address,city,age,contact_number,gender,education FROM users WHERE city='$city'";
```

Comment: Strip tags is not really necessary and should be explained